In a MAUI iOS application, Is it possible to include a native (Swift) app extension?
I'm having trouble with custom notification app extensions and MAUI.  I'm wrapping a native library I have used successfully with Xamarin Forms, but since our MAUI conversion, this extension seems to be having memory problems causing it to crash when the Custom UI for the notification should be rendered.
To work around this, is it possible to include a native app extension file inside a MAUI app deployment?
